# PATH problem when adding postgresql to .bash_profile

Tags: linux, postgresql

Good day all,

After I installed postgresql, adding an export PATH variable into the bash_profile and then restarting it caused all of my default PATH variables to not work anymore, including /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, and my homebrew paths. I removed it and everything worked again. Any way I can get this to work without breaking my PATH configuration?

This is what it looks like:

`nano ~/.bash_profile`

Added:
`export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin/psql"`

Reloaded:
`source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 5):

The difference between

```
PATH="/some/new/bin"         # wrong (in your case)
```

and

```
PATH="$PATH:/some/new/bin"   # correct (in your case)
```

is that the first *replaces* the value of the `PATH` variable while the second *appends to* the value of the same variable.

The line in your file should have read

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin"
```

Notice that `$PATH` should be a `:`-delimited list of directories. Names of individual binaries should not be listed here, only the names (paths) of directories where the shell should look for them.

You don't usually need to `export` the `PATH` since it's already exported.

---

If the value that you append to `PATH` is *correct* or not, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH="/my/path/bin:$PATH"
```